# Ограничение частоты кадров Unity Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Внутри андроид приложения максимальная частота кадров - 60 fps.
Видно что она ограничена, поскольку ниже опускается часто, а выше - никогда, даже в самые ресурсосвободные моменты. 
Как убрать это ограничение?

Поставил на нажатие кнопки следующий код

```
Application.targetFrameRate = 0;
QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
```

В редакторе после нажатия выставляется максимальная частота кадров без ограничений. В андроиде - всё равно ограничено чем то на 60.
Нигде более в проекте

```
Application.targetFrameRate
QualitySettings.vSyncCount
```

не используются. Что может еще ограничивать частоту кадров? Как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 1):

Возникает закономерный вопрос, а зачем вам частота обновления кадров выше 60? На большинстве андроид девайсов максимумом является 30, на некоторых 60. Если вы на устройствах с ограничением 60 fps выставите большее число fps картинка от этого не станет более плавной или красивой, единственный эффект, который вы получите - увеличение энергопотребления, то есть батарейка будет сажаться быстрее.

Эти утверждения также верны и для других платформ, например iOS и PC, на которых *небольшое количество устройств* поддерживает 120 fps, но далеко не все. И в случае большинства PC, если ваш монитор и видеокарта могут отрисовывать только 60 fps - все карды свыше этого числа не дадут никакой пользы. Только на PC это не критично, потому что питается он от сети, в отличии от смартфонов, заряд батареи которых ограничен.

Помимо этого необоснованно высокое число fsp на смартфонах приводит также к большему нагреванию устройства, что тоже не очень хорошо.

Так же, если вы посмотрите гайды по оптимизации приложений от самих Unity, то найдете там советы по поводу ограничения fps, да и в целом подобный подход одна из самых частых и обязательных практик по оптимизации игр.

Comment: Элементарно, для профайлинга. Когда у тебя искусственно режется фпс, то не видно просадок, что хорошо для конечного пользователя но не очень удобно при разработке.

Comment: Подобное уже относится к разряду "преждевременной оптимизации". Зачем пытаться лечить просадку со 100fps до 60? Если при этом наверняка есть более слабые места. Если вы думаете про слабые девайсы - в магазинах большой выбор слабых устройств в пределах 10к и ниже. Получай на таких устройствах стабильный 30-60fsp можно уже ни о чем не беспокоиться

Comment: а разлочить максимальное ограничение все-таки не получится. В большинстве случаев и попытка отключить VSYNC тоже не даст результата. Например на ios выключить VSYNC нельзя никак

Comment: Это с каких пор "не все PC поддерживают 120fps"? PC поддерживают столько фпс, сколько выдаст приложение, вопрос в том, что при 120fps и 60hz мониторе половина кадров просто не отрисуется. Но это уже вопрос другой, такой подход как минимум уменьшает inpup lag. К вопросу PC не относится, но вы не путайте, пожалуйста, людей.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker половина кадров просто не отрисуется.  - и это и имеется в виду под "не поддерживается". То есть цп может больше кадров, а остальное нет

Comment: @vmchar я вам уже пояснил - input lag. Это уже причина делать фпс выше, чем частота развертки в 2 раза, например.